# RAM not fully usable in 64-bit Ubuntu GNU/Linux

Tags: ram, bios

Greetings Ubuntu Community,
I have 4 GB of DDR2 RAM and an x86_64 CPU and Ubuntu OS. When I am in Ubuntu I notice from the details section in settings that I have 3.86 GB of RAM when I am sure that I have 4 GB of RAM. I also checked this from the BIOS and it says that the capacity and usable size is 4096 MB (4 GB). Can anyone please provide me with a reason and a solution to this?

Thanks & Regards
Isaac Cilia Attard

Comment: What kind of Motherboard and VGA do you have?

Comment: No I am using a discrete Nvidia Ge force 8400 GS with 512 MB video RAM.

Comment: Take a look [Here](https://copy.com/ZWYl77HTbe1Ik6OX), and [Here](https://copy.com/24sBrkKpHbW1FR7R).

Comment: I couldn't find that in my BIOS, I checked the Advanced tab then the chipset and then I checked both Southbridge and Northbridge, but I couldn't find anything of what you mentioned. This may be useful to other BIOSes though.

Comment: That came from your board`s manual.  It should be there.  See if there is a BIOS update, or try to contact the manufacturer.  Because the amount of missing RAM is something an On-board video would use.

Comment: I checked the motherboard manual and I noticed the option but when I enter the BIOS to check it I couldn't find it! It could be that it was taken off with a newer release since I updated the BIOS recently this past summer. I will check for newer BIOS updates. Any other solutions though?

Answer (score 0):

This is your on-board video card stealing your main RAM as it has no VRAM of itself.

2 possibilities to solve this issue:

1. Disable the on-board video *not the GPU* in your BIOS.

   - On newer BIOSes, disable 'Hybrid' mode and set it to discrete GPU only (NVidia in your particular case)
   - On older BIOSes, you can choose how much RAM to allocate to the on-board video, with 0 disabling it)
2. Disable through hardware switch. (Not for the faint at heart)

   Download your computer's *Service Manual*, disassemble your PC, disable the video hardware switch.

Comment: I have a legacy AMI BIOS(not UEFI) but I can't find the on board video option, I only have the PCIE>IGP thing which is set to use PCIE first if found!

Comment: Another thing is that in Windows I used to have full 4GB of RAM whilst in Linux I have 3.9 GB and no settings where changed.

Comment: :) That could be a rounding issue...  I can't help you with your BIOS settings unless you post pictures of your full BIOS settings (going through all of the screens as I don't have the exact same hardware you do)

Comment: I will try to post something soon

Comment: @IsaacCiliaAttard, as the above answered your original question, how about clicking the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**